# How do I make a button timer in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I was creating an obby in Roblox, and I wanted to make a button that a player could step on to make the platforms in front of them solid. I checked the documentation, and I found nothing that seemed to help. Here is my code: (Ignore e, ee, eee, bt, bt1, bt2, and tch. They are my parts/variables/function names)

```
bt = game.Workspace.e.SurfaceGui.ButtonTimer
bt1 = game.Workspace.ee.SurfaceGui.ButtonTimer1
bt2 = game.Workspace.eee.SurfaceGui.ButtonTimer2

bt.Text = "hi "
bt1.Text = "hi "
bt2.Text = "hi "

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(tch)
    if tch.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        game.Workspace.e.Transparency = 0
        game.Workspace.e.CanCollide = true
        game.Workspace.ee.Transparency = 0
        game.Workspace.ee.CanCollide = true
        game.Workspace.eee.Transparency = 0
        game.Workspace.eee.CanCollide = true
        bt.Text = "10"
        bt1.Text = "10"
        bt2.Text = "10"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "9"
        bt1.Text = "9"
        bt2.Text = "9"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "8"
        bt1.Text = "8"
        bt2.Text = "8"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "7"
        bt1.Text = "7"
        bt2.Text = "7"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "6"
        bt1.Text = "6"
        bt2.Text = "6"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "5"
        bt1.Text = "5"
        bt2.Text = "5"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "4"
        bt1.Text = "4"
        bt2.Text = "4"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "3"
        bt1.Text = "3"
        bt2.Text = "3"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "2"
        bt1.Text = "2"
        bt2.Text = "2"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "1"
        bt1.Text = "1"
        bt2.Text = "1"
        wait(1)
        bt.Text = "0"
        bt1.Text = "0"
        bt2.Text = "0"
        game.Workspace.e.Transparency = 0.75
        game.Workspace.e.CanCollide = false
        game.Workspace.ee.Transparency = 0.75
        game.Workspace.ee.CanCollide = false
        game.Workspace.eee.Transparency = 0.75
        game.Workspace.eee.CanCollide = false
    else 
        game.Workspace.e.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
    end
end)
```

Comment: Is there anything about this code that doesn't work? Or are you looking for a way to clean up your code with something "more official"? The `wait()` function that you're already using yields the current thread so it is one way to make a timer-like function work.

Comment: The code doesn’t work. I’m pretty sure the defining of bt, bt1, and bt2 is where the code fails.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a timer in my game, I will share the code with you:

```
local timer = script.Parent
local minutes = 1
local seconds = 9

local adm = script.Parent.Parent

repeat
    if seconds <= 0 then
        minutes = minutes - 1
        seconds = 59
    else
        seconds = seconds - 1
    end
    if seconds <= 9  then
        timer.Text = "Vote time: "..tostring(minutes)..":0"..tostring(seconds)
    else
        timer.Text = "Vote time: "..tostring(minutes)..":"..tostring(seconds)
    end
    wait(1)
until minutes <= 0 and seconds <= 0
```